# How to pass configurable values to Ballerina during Docker runtime?

Tags: docker, ballerina

I need to pass configurable values to my Ballerina script while running it in Docker.

This is my configurable variable declaration in my code

```php
configurable string host = ?;
configurable int port = ?;
configurable string user = ?;
configurable string password = ?;
configurable string database = ?; 

final mysql:Client mysqlClient = check new (host = host, port = port, user = user, password = password, database = database);
```

Then I used the following command to run the image I crated

```
docker run -d -p 9090:9090 <image>:<tag>
```

Since c2c does not bundle `Config.toml` file into the Docker image, how could these values be passed to the Docker image during runtime?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options:

1. Specify the content of Config.toml as an environment variable `docker run -e "BAL_CONFIG_DATA=param1=\"ParamValue\"" <image>`. Alternatively if you have the Config.toml locally, you can do `docker run -e "BAL_CONFIG_DATA=$(cat Config.toml)" <image>`
2. Mount the Config.toml file into the docker container and pass an evironment variable with `docker run -e "BAL_CONFIG_FILES=</path/to/Config.toml inside container>" <image>`

Additionally, if you are using something like docker compose, we have an example as well.  https://github.com/ballerina-guides/gcp-microservices-demo/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

c2c does not pack additional resources in the container. You have to manually copy additional files into the container, you can find a example here https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerina-c2c/tree/master/examples/copy-files-to-container